# How to verify that at least one point fall into a polygon with Postgis?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis

I have two tables where table `A` has a geometry (4326) column that contains surfaces (~20M). A second table `B` has ~ 500K points (4326). What I want to do is "flagging" (adding a boolean column) every single surface in `A` that contains at least one of the points in `B`.

I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_data AS
    SELECT
        A.*,
        (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT ST_Contains(A.geom, B.geom) FROM B)) as flagged
    FROM A;
```

But I got all "flagged" values as `true` (which is impossible).

With joins/lateral I didn't go far too.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want If a box's lower surface is x=1, do you want a point on x=1 to return true or false?

Comment: Yes, just if the point is included or not

Comment: This also looks like you're caching the results for mere performance improvements. I would suggest under normal circumstances a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. I wouldn't use `EXISTS`, which is really only useful for reducing a set. I would go with `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and then `coalesce` the result. See how this performs.

```
SELECT a.id, 
  coalesce(result, false) AS flag
FROM a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT true
  FROM b 
  WHERE ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom)
  LIMIT 1
) AS r(result);
```

This should work on an index if you have a spatial index on `a.geom` and `b.geom` (and you should have indexes for this workload). This also looks like you're caching the results for mere performance improvements. I would suggest under normal circumstances a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

Alternatively you should be able to go,

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  bool_or(b.geom IS NOT NULL) AS flag
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
  ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: `select` in the lateral join is missing of columns?

Comment: @Randomize fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ST_Contains will return a value in any case (i.e. if the spatial relationship is true/false). Instead, I would write the query as follows:

```
   SELECT 
     a.id, 
     count(b.geom)>0 as flag
   FROM tbl a 
    LEFT JOIN tbl b 
   ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom)
   GROUP BY a.id
```

or alternatively:

```
   SELECT 
     a.id, 
     CASE WHEN count(b.geom)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as flag
   FROM tbl a 
    LEFT JOIN tbl b 
   ON ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom)
   GROUP BY a.id
```